# Background color of the second flex item is also applied to the first item?

Tags: reactjs, css, flexbox

```
<div style={{ display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column' }}>
    <div style={{ zIndex: 1050, height: '50px', position: 'fixed', width: '100%'}}>
    </div>
    <div style={{ position: 'relative' ,height: '250px', backgroundColor: 'green' }}>
    </div>
</div>
```

Background color green is applied to both inner divs but i don't want the first inner div to have a background color of green?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the first div is fixed and has a transparent background. Try adding a background color to the first div:

```
<div style={{ display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column' }}>
    <div style={{ zIndex: 1050, height: '50px', position: 'fixed', width: '100%', backgroundColor: 'white'}}>
    </div>
    <div style={{ position: 'relative' ,height: '250px', backgroundColor: 'green' }}>
    </div>
</div>
```

Alternatively you could set margin-top on the second div to 50px (the height of the first div)

Answer (score 1):

The first element has a `{position: 'fixed'}` [rule](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position). That means the second one will overlap it.
On top of that, the background color of it is transparent (by default).

See example with different color:

```js
const Example = () => (
  <div style={{ display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column' }}>
      <div style={{ zIndex: 1050, height: '50px', position: 'fixed', width: '100%', backgroundColor: 'red'}}>
      </div>
      <div style={{ position: 'relative' ,height: '250px', backgroundColor: 'green' }}>
      </div>
  </div>
);

ReactDOM.render(<Example/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"/>
```

Comment: Thanks but  i want to fix the first div.

Comment: Its still fixed, but note that i changed its bg color to red. it was transparent in your example. that's why you thought its green